# In Shiny/ bslib, how can you arrange cards horizontally when the cards are generated from a json?

Tags: r, shiny, bslib

I am trying to create a simple bslib app that will showcase some products the team have developed. This app should be easy to update by just editing a json file with the product details to create or edit product cards. Each product card should fill the page horizontally, with 4 cards per row. However, when I attempt to automate the creation of the product cards using lapply and a custom function that configures the card based on the list/json data, the cards default to being arranged vertically, and I cannot make them horizontal.

The reprex below shows roughly what I am trying to do, which is:

- Use a custom *produce_card*_ function with lapply to create a list of cards
- Insert the list of cards into a nav_panel element inside a page_navbar app
- Have the cards arranged horizontally, 4 per row.

It's only the last bullet point I've been unable to figure out

```
library(bslib)
library(jsonlite)
library(shiny)
library(glue)
library(bsicons)

# Product List (eventually to be moved to a editable JSON)
products <- list(
  "p1" = list(
    title = "P1",
    icon = "pie-chart",
    info = "This is Product 1"
  ),
  p2 = list(
    title = "P2",
    icon = "book",
    info = "This is Product 2"
  )
)

# Function that returns a product card based on given list
produce_card <- function(card_config) {

  title <- card_config[["title"]]
  icon <- card_config[["icon"]]
  info <- card_config[["info"]]

  card(
    card_header(title, class = "fs-5 bg-primary"),
    card_body(
      value_box(
        title,
        value = info,
        showcase = bs_icon(icon)
      )
    ),
    max_height = "50%"
  )

}

# Produce the cards list to use in nav_panel below
cards_list <- lapply(products, produce_card)

# Shiny App
ui <- page_navbar(
  title = "Product Catalogue",
  bg = "purple",

  nav_panel(
    title = "Catalogue",
    icon = bs_icon("journal-bookmark-fill"),
    align = "right",
    layout_column_wrap(
      width = 0.25,
      cards_list

    )
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  "Each product card should fill the page horizontally, with 4 cards per row": that sounds like a contradiction to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to unsplice your list of cards using `!!!` (or call `layout_column_wrap` using `do.call`). Additionally before unsplicing you have to unname your list of cards as

> named arguments become attributes on the containing htmltools::tag element. (see `?layout_column_wrap`).

```r
library(bslib)
library(jsonlite)
library(shiny)
library(glue)
library(bsicons)

# Shiny App
ui <- page_navbar(
  title = "Product Catalogue",
  bg = "purple",
  nav_panel(
    title = "Catalogue",
    icon = bs_icon("journal-bookmark-fill"),
    align = "right",
    layout_column_wrap(
      width = .25,
      !!!unname(cards_list)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
#> 
#> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3490
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We could use  `fluidRow()` in combination with `column()`:
I have replicated card 1 and 2 to have 4 cards:

```
#tar_i(bsicons)
library(bslib)
library(jsonlite)
library(shiny)
library(glue)
library(bsicons)

# Product List (eventually to be moved to a editable JSON)
products <- list(
  p1 = list(
    title = "P1",
    icon = "pie-chart",
    info = "This is Product 1"
  ),
  p2 = list(
    title = "P2",
    icon = "book",
    info = "This is Product 2"
  ),
  p3 = list(
    title = "P1",
    icon = "pie-chart",
    info = "This is Product 1"
  ),
  p4 = list(
    title = "P2",
    icon = "book",
    info = "This is Product 2"
  )
)

# Function that returns a product card based on given list
produce_card <- function(card_config) {
  
  title <- card_config[["title"]]
  icon <- card_config[["icon"]]
  info <- card_config[["info"]]
  
  card(
    card_header(title, class = "fs-5 bg-primary"),
    card_body(
      value_box(
        title,
        value = info,
        showcase = bs_icon(icon)
      )
    ),
    max_height = "150%" # changed
  )
  
}

# Produce the cards list to use in nav_panel below
cards_list <- lapply(products, produce_card)

card_columns <- lapply(cards_list, column, width = 3) # added

ui <- page_navbar(
  title = "Product Catalogue",
  bg = "purple",
  nav_panel(
    title = "Catalogue",
    icon = bs_icon("journal-bookmark-fill"),
    align = "right",
    fluidRow(card_columns) ## added
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]